# email in inbox Iphone app don't match with format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, character-encoding, gmail, sendgrid

I send a email with sendGrid Api V3.
When a receive email from web. It work format
[image]

But when i open mail with default app on iphone. It wrong format:

[image]

I use Sendgrid Api v3 to send mail. Pls Someone can help me solve this error...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you lost formatting... it almost seems like you're looking at the text version. I would recommend testing the email in something like Litmus, which will let you see the email on different platforms.

Also try looking at the email in different clients (Gmail, Outlook, etc), and see if maybe you're just sending a text version only.

I really like this gem https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener
When you're in local development, it will open the email in a browser window when it sends, so you can actually see what you're sending as well.